# Using field of type ListAttribute of static metamodel in a CriteriaQuery

Tags: java, jpa, criteria-api

I have the following entity

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "merchants")
public class Merchant implements Serializable {
...
    @ElementCollection
    @CollectionTable(name = "keywords", joinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "merchant_id"))
    private List<String> keywords;
...
}
```

which has corresponding static metamodel

```
@Generated(value = "org.hibernate.jpamodelgen.JPAMetaModelEntityProcessor")
@StaticMetamodel(Merchant.class)
public abstract class Merchant_ {
...
    public static volatile ListAttribute<Merchant, String> keywords;
...
}
```

How do I write queries using `CriteriaBuilder` to check if `keywords` attribute contains given value?

Answer (score 0):

It turned out to be pretty straightforward

```
    String keyword = "<KEYWORD>";

    CriteriaBuilder cb = em.getCriteriaBuilder();
    CriteriaQuery<Merchant> query = cb.createQuery(Merchant.class);
    Root<Merchant> root = query.from(Merchant.class);

    query.select(root).where(
            cb.isMember(keyword, root.get(Merchant_.keywords)));

    return em.createQuery(query).getResultList();
```

But original task is to find entities which contain at least one keyword from a given collection. For now I don't see any better solution rather that unite `isMemeber` predicate with `or` clause for each item in keyword collection. However there are not so many of them are expected to be.

But any better solution is appreciated.